# Quality Center administration via REST API

Tags: rest, hp-quality-center

I'm currently working with the HP Quality Center REST API which works pretty good for creating and reading entities.

But I'd like to perform some administrative tasks that way. Is it possible to add or remove users from projects and (un)assign groups to them? I didn't find anything relevant in the documentation about that.

I'm using the following set-up:

- .NET 4.0 client
- Quality Center 11

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The REST API in ALM 11.0 (the version you have) is focused on objects stored in Quality Center / ALM, such as requirements, defects and tests and associated history (audits). You will have to use the ALM Site Admin API to add user to a site, to a project, to a group, etc...
Site Admin API reference for ALM 11: http://support.openview.hp.com/selfsolve/document/KM997954

Note: the user has to exist in the site admin schema so that it can be added to a project.

Starting with ALM 11.5, there is the possibility to add (PUT) a user to a project. Reference - ALM REST API 11.5: http://support.openview.hp.com/selfsolve/document/KM1413621
In general though, administrative tasks are best covered by the site admin API than the REST API.

Comment: I just tried checking this, both the links are broken.